# Check urls before blocking

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I currently use the following code to block specific urls.It works fine but now i want to do some actions for some specific urls that are **NOT** blocked Before chrome process the cilent request.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(d){
  return {cancel:true};
},{urls:["https://somesite.com/account/*",
         "http://evilsite.com"   
         ]},
  ["blocking"]);
```

Say for e.g i want to get the urls of every url that the user visit with addon on.(Just a simple case here...ofcourse i am excluding the blocked sites here)

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(d){
      console.log(d.url); // doesn't work
      return {cancel:true};
    },{urls:["https://somesite.com/account/*",
             "http://evilsite.com"   
             ]},
      ["blocking"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove the the filter (or rather, make it all-inclusive) and conditionally block:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(d){
    console.log(d.url);
    if(d.url.indexOf('https://somesite.com/account/') >= 0) {
      return {cancel:true};
    }
  },
  { urls:["<all_urls>"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Alternatively, you could have two listeners, one that blocks based on pattern, and one that does-the-other-thing. It may be better for performance if your other operation is not blocking.

You'll need the `"<all_urls>"` permission in the manifest.